# Instantly update React Native app after JWT changes

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks, jwt

I have a React Native where I use a JWT to store user preferences and metadata.

When I change the JWT on the webapp, a POST function is called that updates the user's settings. This works fine, however the user changes the theme (which is stored by the JWT), the app doesn't automatically use the new theme. I can keep switching between pages in the app and eventually the new theme shows up everywhere, but I want it to be right away.

Here is how the JWT is loaded each time a page on the app loads:

```
  const getData = async () => {
    const value1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@myapp:jwt')
    setJWT(JSON.parse(value1))
    setTheme(value1?.is_new_theme)
    return JSON.parse(value1)
  }
```

And here is how I call the POST function to update a user's preferred theme:

```
  const onToggleSwitch = async () => {
    getData().then((value) => {
      fetch(`${API_URL}/profile/${value?.username}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          toggle_theme: !isSwitchOn,
        }),
      })
    }).then(() => {
      setIsSwitchOn(!isSwitchOn)
      //RNRestart()  // I tried importing this function but it didn't work
      navigation.navigate('Home') // The homepage still displays in the old theme
    })
  }
```

Is there something I can do to make the change "instant"? Is it possible to have it stored in the JWT this way and have the app reflect the change right away?

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: I have realized that when I navigate between pages after switching the theme, the component doesn't "reload". I've tried switching `useEffect` for `useFocusEffect` but I get a cryptic error with the `useFocusEffect` function. Here is the `useEffect` that loads each page (and apparently doesn't rerun when I navigate back after switching the theme:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then((value) => {
      fetch(`${API_URL}/home/${value?.username}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e))
        .then(async (res) => {
          const response = await res.json();
          //parse all the response stuff
          setResponse(JSON.parse(response));
        });
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

My thought is that `getData` only gets called the first time the page loads (before the user switches the theme) and is not called again after.